# Generating a truncated normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, python, random-variable, probabilistic-programming

I want to write code, say in Python to generate a truncated normal distributed random variable on the interval $[a,b]$. I have a standard function, call it N which will
generate a normally distributed random value. Will the following algorithm generate
a truncated normal distributed random  value correctly?

```
 num = a - 1
 while num >= a && num <= b:
    num = N()
 end while
```

Notice that the while loop will always run at least once.

Here is the corrected code:

```
 num = a - 1
 while num < a && num > b:
    num = N()
 end while
```

Here is the corrected code:

```
 num = a - 1
 while num < a || num > b:
    num = N()
 end while
```

Comment: Your code will run until the first time it generates a number out of the range, then stop - probably not what you want.

Comment: @jbowman  You are right. I will fix the code.

Comment: How is `num` going to be simultaneously (`&&`) `< a` and `> b`?

Comment: @jbowman You are right. I will fix the code.

Comment: The code will work in theory, but it might never terminate (at least within the lifetime of the universe) unless $|a|$ and $|b|$ are both very small.  (Try this with $a=b=10,$ for instance.) What are the ranges of values of $a$ and $b$ you plan to supply to your function?

Comment: @whuber I was thinking of a = -3 and b = 3. With these values, I would expect the while loop to terminate very quickly.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  I should also clarify I had in mind generating truncated variables on the set $(-\infty, a]\cup[b,\infty)$ rather than $[a,b].$  In the latter case (as in your question) you run into severe problems when both $a$ and $b$ have the same sign and both exceed $3$ or so in size; or when $|b-a|$ is tiny.